# the way grep command \< and \> work

Tags: command-line, grep

myfile.txt contains the following:

```
hello (ab)
hello ab
hello abcd
```

I've tried the following command:

```
$grep '\<ab\>' myfile.txt
```

`\<` means a beginning of a word and `\>` means end of word.

So I thought my grep command is equivalent to `$grep ' ab ' myfile.txt`
.I expected my output to be

```
hello ab
```

But it matches:

```
hello (ab)
hello ab
```

How is a word defined? Is it a string with a space in front of it and one more space following the string?

Comment: to get what you want do `grep ' \<ab\>' myfile.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man grep`

> ```
>    The Backslash Character and Special Expressions
>        The  symbols  \<  and  \>  respectively  match  the empty string at the
>        beginning and end of a word.  The symbol \b matches the empty string at
>        the  edge  of a word, and \B matches the empty string provided it's not
>        at the edge of a word.  The symbol \w is a synonym for [_[:alnum:]] and
>        \W is a synonym for [^_[:alnum:]].
> ```

In other words, a *word* is a sequence of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and a *word boundary* is the empty string before or after anything else - including punctuation such as `(` and `)` as well as whitespace. So:

```
$ echo 'word-boundary' | grep -o '\<\w*\>'
word
boundary

$ echo 'word_boundary' | grep -o '\<\w*\>'
word_boundary

$ echo 'word(bound)ary' | grep -o '\<\w*\>'
word
bound
ary
```

For more information see [Regex Tutorial - Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for an exact word, you need to use the option -w. See the below command:

```
grep -w "hello ab" file.txt
```

the output is as you expected.

```
hello ab
```

If you want the exact name "hello ab" then use -w option with grep command.

For learning more options of grep command, please refer the article for grep command written by me: https://screwlinux.com/how-to-use-grep-command-in-linux/